# Change format of inline code evaluation in org-mode's LaTeX-export

Tags: latex, export, org-mode

I have a code block in an org document

```
#+NAME: result_whatever
#+BEGIN_SRC python :session data :results value :exports none 
return(8.1 - 5)
#+END_SRC
```

which I evaluate inline:

```
Now, does this work? Let's see: call_result_whatever(). I'd be surprised ...
```

When exporting to LaTeX, this generates the following:

```
Now, does this work? Let's see:  \texttt{3.1}. I'd be surprised \ldots{}
```

However, I don't want the results to be displayed in *monospace*. I want it to be formatted in "normal" upright font, without any special markup.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you provide the minimal org document? And state your system? And take care of the formatting? And state why a simple `query-replace` doesn't work for you?

Comment: thanks for you comment, @abo-abo! I'm very new to Emacs and org-mode. Probably `query-replace` could work for me, but I don't know about it. You could provide an appropriate answer, which I could then probably accept ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get it work using the optional header arguments which can be added to `call_function()`.

I don't have LaTeX installed on this system so can't fully test the outputs to ensure they come out exactly as desired, I'm using the plain text output to compare instead.  However you can use the following syntax as part of your `call` to modify the results.

```
Now, does this work? Let's see call_results_whatever()[:results raw].
I'd be surprised ...
```

Without the `[:results raw]` the output to Plain Text (Ascii buffer) is `` Let's see `3.0999999999999996'. ``.  With the added results it becomes `Let's see 3.0999999999999996.`

For full details of the available `results` keywords as well as other optional header arguments for the inline blocks please see [Evaluation Code Blocks](http://orgmode.org/manual/Evaluating-code-blocks.html) and [Results arguments](http://orgmode.org/manual/results.html).

Answer (score 1):

this is 5 years later.  apparently in org-mode 8.2 or so, a new variable was introduced (documenting in "Evaluating Code Blocks" in the org-mode manual, but this from etc/ORG-NEWS in the source tree):

> *** New option: org-babel-inline-result-wrap
>
> If you set this to the following
>
> : (setq org-babel-inline-result-wrap "$%s$")
>
> then inline code snippets will be wrapped into the formatting string.

so, to eliminate \texttt{}

```
(setq org-babel-inline-result-wrap "%s")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem of this type can be solved in two ways:

### 1: Easy does it:

A plain `query-replace` on the exported buffer.
Once you're in the LaTeX buffer,

1. `beginning-of-buffer` or <kbd>M-<</kbd>
2. `query-replace` or <kbd>M-%</kbd>

   - enter `\texttt` as the string that you want to replace
   - enter nothing as the replacement
   - continue to replace each match interactively
     with `y`/`n` or just replace everything with `!`

### 2: But I wanna!

The second way is to nag the org-mode mailing list into
implementing a switch or an option for your specific case.
While it's necessary sometimes, it also produces a system
with thousands of switches, which can become unwieldy.
You can try, but I don't recommend.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, as it effectively states "it's not possible" -- while that's not what I wanted to hear, it tells me I'll have to use a custom string prepended to the evaluation results, and then do a global search-and-replace. Without the custom prefix, all instances of `\texttt` will be removed and not only those originating from code evaluation.

Comment: If you provide the working example(it's not working now), and your system, I could have a further look.

Comment: It is possible, the `:results` header option is not new, although I believe it was only added to `call_function()` blocks in the last year or so (I may be wrong).